# Package that calls different classes when given input to?

Tags: java, class, package

I have taken all of my classes from my intro to java college in highschool class, and put them into a package called `gameChoices`. I then made a class that would call these classes when the user asks for them, this is called `whichGame`. I've imported the classes I want called using `import gameChoices`."whatever game it is";. How do I call these classes in `whichGame`? I also have them all as `public static main(string [] args)`, which ones shouldn't have that(I think it's just `whichGame` that should..)? And what would I put instead? Thanks for helping a newbie out :)

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand your question, perhaps you could provide a section of code that you have so far in order to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it is probably to set up a big if/then statement.

```
if(input.equals("t"))
  thisOne.start();
else if(input.equals("a"))
  anotherOne.start();
else if(input.equals("y"))
  yetAnotherOne.start();
```

And so on. Might be a pain if you have a lot of classes, or if they start with the same letter.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I have. So .start(); will initiate it?

Comment: Sorry, I was not trying to imply that `.start()` would actually call your class.  I figured I'd leave it open which method you want to call.  If it's the main method, then `.main()` should work.

Comment: Oh okay haha. I think I understand now, the class name initiates the object, then it's calling the method inside that class. Thanks!

Comment: I agree, I only realize now reflection wasn't _really_ a requirement :) Big if/then sounds better, especially if you have a limited number of games.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but if you need to access a class by its name you can try [Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) and check for exceptions thrown (particularly, ClassNotFoundException). 
Using case-insensitive String equality for the name check, if would allow you to access any existing class of your ClassLoader through reflection.

**Edit**

Here's your main class:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    // initializes your map of letter->game class 
    private static final Map<String, Class<?>> GAMES = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    // constant name of main method for your games
    private static final String MAIN_METHOD_NAME = "main";
    // add your games
    static {
        GAMES.put("c", Chess.class);
        GAMES.put("d", Doom.class);
        // TODO moar gamez
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // prompts the user
            System.out.println("Enter the game's name or starting letter: ");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in)
            );
            // gets the response
            String input = br.readLine();
            br.close();
            // iterates over your games' first letters
            for (String gameName : GAMES.keySet()) {
                // the input starts with one game's first letter...
                if (gameName.startsWith(input.toLowerCase())) {
                    // gets the class
                    GAMES.get(gameName)
                        // gets its main method (typical signature is String[] args)
                        .getMethod(MAIN_METHOD_NAME, String[].class)
                        // invokes its main method with no arguments
                        .invoke((Object) null, (Object) null);
                }
            }
        // handles any disaster
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now here are two "game" classes:

```
package test;

public class Chess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("You've chosen Chess!");

    }

}
```

... and...

```
package test;

public class Doom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("You've chosen Doom!");

    }

}
```

Now set your "Main" class as your... main class. 
When you launch the application, it will query you for an initial letter. 
If you choose "c" or "d", it will print out: "You've chosen [Chess/Doom]!"

I hope this helps you getting started.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being very descriptive, I'll post the code when I get home. In whichGame, I have it ask for them to type the first letter of the game they want. That's stored in a string that is then put in an if statement using .equals() if it equals the letter, it will call the class that they want, like a method. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes it is. If you have only one "game" per alphabet letter, and each of your "game" classes has a main method with the same name (e.g. "main") the logic will be rather trivial. You map your games' names with their class' first letter (it's hard to "discover" all classes for the ClassLoader). You query the letter from the user, and if it's in your map, you to launch the class' main method. You probably don't even need reflection for that after all.

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make sense. So each game starts with its imports, then I put [code] public class "it's game name"{ public static void main(string args[]){}}[/code] they all have this. Will that cause conflicts?

Comment: Hi again, I'm editing my previous answer to illustrate my point better. This solution uses reflection for lack of time, but you can also implement your own logic and ditch reflection entirely (e.g. an if/then loop, etc.)